I don't understand the syntax error in my SQL
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM totaldata, eventvenue, band
WHERE totaldata.band_name = eventvenue.headlin' at line 3
INSERT INTO eventbandrevenue
SELECT DISTINCT eventvenue.eventvenue_id,
totaldata.band_name, 
(0.60*(SELECT DISTINCT eventvenue.ticket_revenue 
    FROM eventvenue, band 
    WHERE eventvenue.headliner = band.band_name), 
(0.60*(SELECT DISTINCT eventvenue.merchanndise_sales
    FROM eventvenue, band 
    WHERE eventvenue.headliner = band.band_name)),
((0.60* (SELECT DISTINCT eventvenue.ticket_revenue 
  FROM eventvenue, band 
  WHERE eventvenue.headliner = band.band_name) 
  + 
  0.60*(SELECT DISTINCT eventvenue.merchanndise_sales 
  FROM eventvenue, band 
  WHERE eventvenue.headliner = band.band_name)))
FROM totaldata, eventvenue, band
WHERE totaldata.band_name = eventvenue.headliner


I do not want to discuss endless SELECT DISTINCT.. but would suggest two things: have a look on modern JOIN-style. Think about the query's end: FROM totaldata, eventvenue, band
WHERE totaldata.band_name = eventvenue.headliner   It is to be CROSS JOIN and highly likely extra data

As well as @Sergey’s comments, you could achieve what you want with simple case statements rather than all those sub-queries

What are you trying to do?!? A [mcve] would make this much clearer.


There are extra opening parentheses before each calculation, causing syntax errors.
merchanndise_sales is likely a typo, probably should be merchandise_sales
The subqueries don't reference the outer query's tables.
The joins in the main query need conditions

Below removes unessessary subqueries and uses explicit joins.
    INSERT INTO eventbandrevenue
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        ev.eventvenue_id,
        td.band_name,
        (0.60 * ev.ticket_revenue) as ticket_revenue_share,
        (0.60 * ev.merchandise_sales) as merchandise_revenue_share,
        (0.60 * (ev.ticket_revenue + ev.merchandise_sales)) as total_revenue_share
    FROM totaldata td
    JOIN eventvenue ev ON td.band_name = ev.headliner
    JOIN band b ON ev.headliner = b.band_name

